# Ctrl + Alt + F1 blank screen in IBM server model x3650

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze, ibm

I have 3 IBM sever, model x3650. I have installed the Debian squeeze OS. After successful OS installation , if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I am getting blank screen only. But If I gives username and password it is accepting. After successful login, I have created the file. Then I have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>F7</kbd> it gives GUI mode. There I am able to see the file which I created in "Ctrl + Alt + F1" mode.

I wants to know , why I am not able to see the screen in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I have installed same OS in same model, 3 servers. All the three servers I am facing the same problem.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try to boot to text only mode ? It is usually called "recovery mode" in Grub.
- Check if you use framebuffer and try to disable it if possible (good link about it: http://kb.digium.com/articles/FAQ/How-to-disable-the-Linux-frame-buffer-if-it-s-causing-problems?retURL=%2Fapex%2FknowledgeProduct&popup=false)

sorry, can't post comments, quite new to this service